# Code providing HTML as output instead of JSON

Tags: python, json, graphql

I have Python code where I am connecting to `"metadata/graphiql"` from **Tableau** Online and then writing a "query". The result should be in JSON format but I'm getting some HTML code instead.

```
import requests

graphql_url = "https://<server-name>/metadata/graphiql"

metadata_query='''
query {
  workbooks{
    name
    }
  }'''

response=requests.post(graphql_url, json={'query':metadata_query})
print(response.content)

if response.status_code==200:
  print(response.json())
else:
  print('Error:',response.text)
```

I am expecting a JSON output of the `metadata_query`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Is the HTML preceded with "Error:" ?

Comment: My bad , the above code mentioned by me gives error as below File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: That will probably be because the response is not JSON

Comment: but I am expecting output as json only , not sure where that gap is or am i missing out anything

Comment: Try printing response.text regardless of the HTTP response code

Comment: tried response.text & response.content but it gives result in HTML not json

Comment: Have you tried rendering the HTML response if your favourite browser?

Comment: did not actually understand the statement,,can you please elaborate?

Comment: It is possible that the API has returned HTML content with HTTP status 200 even though you were expecting JSON. You need to inspect the HTML as it may indicate some kind of error

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the "graphql_url" location, Check again with error handling response code (response.status_code).

Comment: graphql_url is right accept the <server-name> portion where it should be actual site name/server name which I cannot provide here